# Selenium with python

Tags: python, selenium

on a Mac, using virtualenv and python to try Selenium. I copied and pasted the sample code verbatim from the Simple Usage section on http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/getting-started.html
and ran it. Firefox starts up, but nothing happens. After a short while of doing nothing, Firefox closes and I get the error pasted below

Originally I thought the problem was version differences. I'm on FF v28 and Selenium 2.41

Any ideas?

```
(venv)1:tests danny$ python acceptance.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "acceptance.py", line 4, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
  File "/Users/danny/Sites/school/asa/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 59, in __init__
    self.binary, timeout),
  File "/Users/danny/Sites/school/asa/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/extension_connection.py", line 47, in __init__
    self.binary.launch_browser(self.profile)
  File "/Users/danny/Sites/school/asa/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/firefox_binary.py", line 61, in launch_browser
    self._wait_until_connectable()
  File "/Users/danny/Sites/school/asa/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/firefox_binary.py", line 105, in _wait_until_connectable
    self.profile.path, self._get_firefox_output()))
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: "Can't load the profile. Profile Dir: /var/folders/sm/tx8hy4bx1cgg176rthqylwh00000gn/T/tmpvhQdUO Firefox output: *** LOG addons.xpi: startup\n*** LOG addons.xpi: Skipping unavailable install location app-system-share\n*** LOG addons.xpi: checkForChanges\n*** LOG addons.xpi: No changes found\n*** Blocklist::_loadBlocklistFromFile: blocklist is disabled\nJavaScript error: chrome://browser/content/urlbarBindings.xml, line 648: aUrl is undefined\n"
```

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error, after adjusting local firewall rules it started to work. I didn't have time to check where the needed port is defined, it seemed to be randomly picked, so temporarily I allowed all TCP ports locally (127.0.0.1 -> 127.0.0.1) and after that it worked fine. I actually used the same code from readthedocs.org.